# Trying to run a thread inside another thread not working

Tags: python, list

I'm constructing a script that fetches ids from an api that can take many ids at once I am getting those ids from a range, but I wish to get more info about said ids way faster so I tried this:

```
import ctypes
import random, requests
from threading import Thread, Lock, active_count

threadc = 100
clear_file = False
exclude_banned = True

if clear_file:
    open('usernames.txt', 'w')

lock = Lock()
usernames = []
xi = []
def thread():
    while idlists:
        idlist = idlists.pop()
        try:
            r = requests.post('https://users.roblox.com/v1/users', json={'userIds': idlist, 'excludeBannedUsers': exclude_banned}, timeout=5).json()['data']
            n = [f['name'] for f in r]
            xi = [f['id'] for f in r]
            for i in range(threadc):
                Thread(target=thredc).start()
            def thredc():
                while xi:
                    ix = xi.pop()
                    try:
                        e = requests.get(f'https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/{ix}').json()
                        if e['description'] == False:
                            d = ''
                        if e['description'] == True:
                            if '\n' or ':' in e['description']:
                                d = d.replace('\n', ' \\n ').replace(':', ';,')
                                d = ':' + d[:0]
                        usernames.append(f"{e['name']}:{e['id']}{d}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        xi.append(ix)
        except Exception as e:
            idlists.append(idlist)

min = 1994000
max = 1994020

ids = list(range(min,max))
idlists = [ids[x:x+200] for x in range(0, len(ids), 200)]
print(f'\nLoaded {len(idlists)} ID lists for {len(ids)} IDs')

for i in range(threadc):
    Thread(target=thread).start()

while active_count() > 1:
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f'ID Scraper | Remaining ID lists: {len(idlists)}')
with open(f'usernames.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines(usernames)

input('Finished!')
```

doesn't finished for me I expect for it to run all 20 or so ids through the users.roblox.com api but it isnt.